# How to process data from an Excel file using Notion AI's text generation tool?

Tags: python, excel, automation, notion-api, notion

I have a large curated data collection in an Excel file that I want to process using Notion AI's text generation tool. I've tried using other text generation tools like Bard and ChatGPT, but the results were not satisfactory. Since Notion AI's text generation tool seems to provide better outcomes, I want to leverage it for this task. However, I'm unsure of how to proceed.

I have some programming background, so I'm willing to explore options involving Notion AI's API if it provides a text generation tool. Alternatively, I'd appreciate any alternate suggestions or approaches to achieve my goal of processing the data using Notion AI's text generation tool.

I have attempted to utilize ChatGPT for processing the data, aiming to automate the process as much as possible. However, the organization I work for expressed dissatisfaction with the results obtained from ChatGPT.

Given this situation, I am seeking guidance on alternative steps or approaches that could help improve the text generation process. I have heard about Notion templates but I'm unsure if they can be of assistance in this context.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: "I need to efficiently process this data as quickly as possible. I tried using ChatGPT to automate the data processing, but the results were unsatisfactory. However, Notion AI provides excellent answers. Unfortunately, I'm unaware of alternative methods to automate the task of extracting data from Excel, processing it using Notion, and subsequently pasting the answers into another Excel sheet."